# Next.js with Apollo - error parameter always undefined

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, next.js

I am using the demo [with-apollo](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo) of next.js and [changing the query](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/45f80409dca104aa824cfbbca13baaf102f2c077/examples/with-apollo/components/PostList.js#L9) in `PostList` to a wrong query to generate an error.

that's the new bad query:

```
query allPosts($first: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
    allPosts(orderBy: createdAt_DESC, first: $first, skip: $skip) {
      wrong-id
      wrong-title
      votes
      url
      createdAt
    }
    _allPostsMeta {
      count
    }
  }
```

However,
while an error is printed on the console [by this line](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/45f80409dca104aa824cfbbca13baaf102f2c077/examples/with-apollo/lib/with-apollo-client.js#L35), [The error parameter](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/45f80409dca104aa824cfbbca13baaf102f2c077/examples/with-apollo/components/PostList.js#L28) on the `Query` component remains undefined.

So when exactly this error gets populated with the actual error?